# What calls the "sessionStarted" event in the speech SDK?

Tags: javascript

In the speech SDK, what triggers the sessionStarted method on the front end. Which method triggers this event?

(Is it the `recognizeOnceAsync`?)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.cognitiveservices.speech.recognizer.sessionstarted?view=azure-dotnet

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-speech?pivots=programming-language-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recognizeOnceAsync triggers a set of lifecycle events of which sessionStarted is the first.